# Run a magic from within a function in Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: jupyter, google-cloud-datalab

I'm looking to use the `%storage` magic in a Datalab notebook, but within a function. The line looks like:

```
%storage write --variable df --object $bucket_object
```

and when calling the function I get this error:

> Undefined variable referenced in command line: $bucket_object

`bucket_object` is defined previously in the function, and this works when running outside a function.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41561706/1840471) regarding a similar question for iPython recommends finding the path and then importing like:

`from IPython.core.magics.display import Javascript`

Is there a similar approach to call a Datalab magic's respective function so that it would work within another function?

Answer (score 3):

The %storage and other similar commands are mostly syntactic sugar over underlying APIs.

For example, in this case google.datalab.storage APIs. Documentation is at http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/google.datalab.storage.html

Something like this might work:

```
import google.datalab.storage as storage

bucket = storage.Bucket(bucket_name)
obj = bucket.object(object_key)
obj.write_stream(data, content_type)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `write_stream` gives this error: "TypeError: write_stream() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)". Based on the [documentation](http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/_modules/google/datalab/storage/_object.html) it looked like `upload` might work instead, but that gave this error: "ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Note that write_stream also takes content type, so it should be obj.write_stream(data, content_type).